# Telerik Splitter Resizing does not working using ASP.net and Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

I am using a web page,Which is consisting 3 splitters.one is left side of the page, second splitter is in Horizontal orientation, which spilts the page as half and the third splitter is in vertical orientation which is above on the horizontal splitter.

Now I get the left pane splitter from my master page and other two splitters are created on the web page itself.  Now my problem is , I am not able resize the splitter. I cant even drag the splitter itself. I am having some resizing (script)methods in my ASPX page for the Splitter as OnClientLoaded , OnClientResized events. But the methods are not get fired when I am trying to resize the splitter.

But I can resize the leftpane splitter which inherited from master page. And also After I resized the left pane splitter ,I can resize the other splitters(Horizontal and Vertical splitters). I dont know whats wrong on my code?

Can anybody please help me on this to resolve this problem?

Here My codes are:

## This is my master page code for creating left pane with splitter:

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="radSplitter" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%"  Skin="Windows7"
        OnClientLoaded="LoadMainSplitterNew" OnClientResized="ResizeMainSplitterNew" VisibleDuringInit="false">
        <telerik:RadPane ID="radLeftPane" CssClass="OverflowStyleLP" Width="20%" Height="100%"
            runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LeftContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </telerik:RadPane>
        <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="radSplitBar" runat="server" CollapseMode="Forward" />
        <telerik:RadPane ID="radRightPane" Width="80%" Height="100%" Scrolling="None" runat="server"
            OnClientResized="afterResizeNew"> <%-- here I am creating the right pane and place my web page on this with the two splitters--%>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="RightContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </telerik:RadPane>
    </telerik:RadSplitter>
```

## This is my code for the Splitters in ASPX page

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSHorizontal" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Skin="Windows7" 
         OnClientLoaded="LoadADSplitterNew" OnClientResized="ResizeADSplitterNew">  

            <telerik:RadPane ID="RadTable" Scrolling="None" runat="server" SkinID="Windows7" >  

                <telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSUpperVert"  runat="server" Orientation="Vertical" Skin="Windows7"  >

                      <telerik:RadPane ID="pnlMap"  Scrolling="Both"   runat="server" SkinID="Windows7">
                                        <telerik:RadTreeView ID="radTree" runat="server" MaxDataBindDepth="4"
                                            OnClientNodeCollapsing="OnClientNodeCollapsing" OnClientNodeExpanded="ClientMapNodeExpanded"
                                            CssClass="no_root_sign" OnClientNodeClicked="mapNodeClicked" OnClientLoad="ExpandRootNode_OnLoad" EnableDragAndDrop="false"
                                            EnableDragAndDropBetweenNodes="false">
                                            <Nodes>
                                                                                                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                            </Nodes>
                                            <CollapseAnimation Duration="100" Type="OutQuint" />
                                            <ExpandAnimation Duration="100" />
                                        </telerik:RadTreeView>                                        
                        </telerik:RadPane>

                       <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="rspBar" runat="server" SkinID="Windows7"  />

                       <telerik:RadPane ID="RadGroup" runat="server" Scrolling="Both" SkinID="Windows7" >
                           <div id="tdGroup" style="font-size: 8pt; font-weight: 100; overflow: hidden;">
                           </div>
                       </telerik:RadPane>

                </telerik:RadSplitter>

             </telerik:RadPane>                 
            <telerik:RadSplitBar ID="RadSplitBar1" runat="server" />
            <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPTable2" Scrolling="None" runat="server" SkinID="Windows7" >
            <telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSLowerVert"  runat="server" Skin="Windows7" Orientation="Vertical" OnClientResized="ResizeMethod">

                      <telerik:RadPane ID="RadDesc" runat="server" SkinID="Windows7">
                                     <div id="pnlDesc" style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;">
                                    </div>                                 
                        </telerik:RadPane>

                </telerik:RadSplitter>
         </telerik:RadPane>
```